# Django forms are not saving any information

Tags: python, django, web

So I have been trying to build a manager of activities with django and I'm still on the scratch. I was trying to test if the code can simply show if a acitivity is done or not, but it don't change anything. Everything looks good to me and I don't know if the error is in the form, in the view that saves the form or in anything else. I already tried to change the widget and fields of form and haven't been succeed in it.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Activity(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_complete = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py:

```
from .models import Activity


class ActivityUpdateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = ['is_complete']
```

views.py:

```
from .models import Activity
from .forms import ActivityUpdateForm


def home(request):
    acts = Activity.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ActivityUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = ActivityUpdateForm()
    
    context = {
        'acts': acts,
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'diary/home.html', context)
```

template:

````
{% for act in acts %}
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ act.title }}</p>
        <p>Is complete: {{ act.is_complete }}</p>
        {{ form }}
        <p>{{ act.author }}</p>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endfor %}```
````

Comment: `form = ActivityUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)` -- Nothing will be saved because you are passing a user instance on `ActivityUpdateForm`, but this form expects an *activity* object not a *user* object

Comment: I put ```instance=request.user``` there because django gave me an error for not passing the author. How can I pass both?

Comment: A user can have many activities, so you need to find a way to get which activity you want to update. For example, if you want to get the first one, you can do: `instance=request.user.activity_set.first()`

Comment: The answer by @Noby will work, but it will fail if user has more than one `Activity`

Comment: It also worked, thank you very much. I didn't what to do with an object_set until now.

Answer (score 0):

This is not elegant, but you just might need to do this:

```
data = Activity.objects.get(author=request.user)
data.is_complete = form.cleaned_data["is_complete"]
data.save()
```

Please delete `form.save()` and write the code above.
i'm not sure if this works, but please give it a try.

Comment: It worked, but can you explain me why it didn't work before?